# Send cart and user to another website to complete checkout process

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

One of my client runs a successful store using WooCommerce, and now he wishes to create another WooCommerce site with the exact same products. But since opening a new actual business is a big deal for him, he wish that after the users has placed items in their cart and clicked on "checkout", the user will be redirected to the first ("original") site and choose the shipping option and payment method and complete the checkout process there.

We have thought about it through, from different aspects, and finally the user insist this is the solution he wants to try.

Can it be done? If yes, does anyone know of a simple way to accomplish it? or what should I consider before trying to implement this solution.

Comment: I don't see the reasoning for creating a duplicate site. Wouldn't you be weirded out if you tried to checkout and were suddenly redirected to a totally new site?

Comment: @helgatheviking You are absolutely right, but... that's what my client have decided, so I  guess we will need to figure out how to do that.

Comment: The client isn't always right. It is partly your job to advice him when he is terribly wrong in terms of both user experience and development difficulty.

Comment: i guess you can do it if he is insist. while clicking on checkout button it is easy but you need to take care of all the products id both website must have same product id.  i can do it. i guess but if all products have same id. create a chat room i can guide you